# Complex copy images with cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know how to do most of these things separately, but I'm having a hard time piecing all the different techniques together. Basically, I have a list of requirements that I would like to accomplish with a single DOS command or batch script.
Requirements:

1. I need to copy all the images named 00000001 or 00000002 (.jpg,JPG,tiff,TIFF) from folders nested 3 layers deep.
2. I need the image renamed with the name of the third folder, which is a serial number (like 78787878.jpg)
3. If there is a duplicate in the destination folder, I would like to append something to the name instead of overwriting the image.

The file structure is

```
USPTO
--HR200713
----792885
------79288705
--------00000001.xml
--------00000002.jpg
----792822
------79288754
--------00000001.xml
--------00000002.jpg
----455185
------8988725
--------00000001.jpg
--HR200399
----792898
------79288700
--------00000001.xml
--------00000002.jpg
----792899
------79288555
--------00000001.xml
--------00000002.jpg
----453321
------8988098
--------00000001.jpg
```

I started out using this code which loops through the folders and performs actions, but it seems to be getting jumbled up. I haven't attempted the 3rd requirement yet.

```
FOR /F %E IN ('DIR /b'); do (cd %E & FOR /F %F IN ('DIR /b'); do (cd %F & FOR /F %G IN ('DIR /b'); do (cd %G & copy 00000002 "path\%H.jpg")))
```

I think something that jumps right to the last folder and sets a variable with the folder name that I can use to rename the image would be the way to go. I'd appreciate guidance for any of the steps. Thanks!

Comment: even if that one liner was in a `batch-file`, it will never work, there is no logic in the complete query, and that is not an insult.. `:)`

Comment: So, to get some clarity, please edit the question and show the folder structure etc. but include exactly what you need. You show `Folder1.1` but you state the third folder is a serial number, so please show me so I can help you.

Comment: @Gerhard I added what the file structure actually looks like. And yeah, I was trying to get a proof of concept first and then I was going to try to create a batch file based on it, but I'm a bit in over my head.

Comment: Well that file structure doesn't match that previously mentioned, _and still included in your question_. You're now looking at four levels deep, and have not provided the structure satisfactorily. In your first example you had directories `Folder1`, `Folder2` etc. at level 2. What we now need to know is whether this code is supposed to be parsing from level 2, or only from level 3. For example has the code got to parse inside all directories from the `HR200713` level, or only from the `792885` level. Also your code is not valid, there is no reason in those commands to use a semicolon `;`.

Comment: @Compo I need something that can go to the deepest directory. I planned on running it from the USPTO folder, meaning I would need it to go 3 layers deeper and run a copy/move command there. At every folder level, there are multiple folders, until it gets to the folder that has the files.

Comment: All you needed to do was to open a Command Prompt, change directory to `USPTO`, _(using either the `CD` or `PushD` command)_, then type `tree /a /f` and press the `[ENTER]` key, then copy and paste the structure without modification, except for removing the first two lines, and changing the first line to read `USPTO`. Then it would have been absolutely clear to everyone exactly what your environment is in order to provide the most efficient responses. Also as I stated previously that is four levels, not three.

Comment: @Compo it's pretty large, but you can see it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVn6j8cE2SjwNFbyYZDYNQ0W2CtMTyAm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And you're definitely not wanting to do anything with any file which isn't named `00000001.jpg`, `00000001.tiff`, `00000002.jpg`, or `00000002.tiff`, _(even though you do not have a single `tiff` file in there)_, is that correct?

Comment: @Compo Correct. There are sometimes capitalized extensions too (like 00000001.JPG), but then I want to move/copy the files and probably delete everything from the source after it is processed.

Comment: You're question is far too broad for this site, it is technically a code request, and off topic. To see the target directories, you could use `@For /D %%G In (%~dp0*)Do @For /D %%H In (%%G\*)Do @For /D %%I In (%%H\*)Do @Echo(%%I` from a batch file, located in `USPTO`. Then you'd just modify the `Echo(%%I` as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `for /?`, especially the text describing 'modifiers', which are extremely helpful.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "USPTO" %%a in (*.jpg *.png *.tiff *.txt) do (
  set "folder=%%~dpa"
  for %%b in ("!folder:~0,-1!") do (
    echo DEBUG: %%~nxb - %%~nxa
    if exist "path\%%~nxb-%%~nxa" (
      echo --- "path\%%~nxb-%%~nxa" already exists ---
      rem replace with code to avoid duplicates if neccessary
    ) else (
      ECHO copy "%%a" "path\%%~nxb-%%~nxa"
    )
  )
)
```

Note I disarmed the `copy` command for security reasons. Remove the `ECHO` to actually enable it after troubleshooting.

Replace `copy` with `move` to move the files instead of copying them.